# How to check if the date('H:i:s') is greater than the night time and less than the start of the day?

Tags: php

I'm developing an automatic darkmode system where when it arrives at 16:00 in the afternoon it is activated and when it arrives at 06:00 in the morning it is disabled, when only setei from 16 it worked until 00:00 but then it didn't work.

```
$date = date('H:i:s');

if ($date > '16:00:00' && $date < '06:00:00' && $autoDark['auto_dark_mode'] == "enable") {
        echo "active";
    }
```

It works:  `$date > '16:00:00' to 00:00`

It works:  `$date > '06:00:00' in 00:00 to 06:00`

But it doesn't work:  `$date > '16:00:00' && $date < '06:00:00'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare UNIX time integers, so use something like this:

```php
$timestr = date("H:i:s");
$time = date_create_from_format("H:i:s", $timestr)->getTimestamp();
if (($time > date_create_from_format("H:i:s", "16:00:00")->getTimestamp() || $time < date_create_from_format("H:i:s", "06:00:00")->getTimestamp()) && $autoDark['auto_dark_mode'] == "enable") {
  echo "active";
};
```

Comment: Works, but alter this `)->getTimestamp()` to but alter this `->getTimestamp())`, thank you

Comment: An error occurred "internal 500", but your first alternative worked, 
$timestr = date("H:i:s");
    $time = strtotime($timestr);
    if (($time > strtotime("16:00:00") || $time < strtotime("06:00:00")) && $autoDark['auto_dark_mode'] == "enable") {
        echo "active";
    };

Answer (score 0):

Now Check This one:

```
$now_time   = date('H:i:s');
$time_start = '16:00:00';
$time_end   = '06:00:00';

if((strtotime($time_start) <= strtotime($now_time) && strtotime($now_time) <= strtotime($time_end)) && ($autoDark['auto_dark_mode'] == "enable"))  {
   echo "active";
}
```

Comment: This wouldn’t work, no time is greater than 16 hrs and lesser than 6 hrs. I tried `strtotime("06:00:00")` and it returns timestamp for 6 AM today, not tomorrow.